# How to make bottom navigation full width when area is clicked on mobile

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to figure out how to make the hover area of the bottom navigation fill the entire area. For Example, if a user selects email, the entire background should fill in with black. As you will see in the attached, there are some areas to the left and right of the selectable areas when accessed.

visit codepen https://codepen.io/nickfs000/pen/LePYqZ

[screen animation of bottom navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN2Om.gif)

Here is what my HTML code looks like and would appreciate the help to figure it out. Maybe I need to create buttons instead?

```
<div class="bottom-menu-view">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="mailto:flipfundnm@gmail.com">email</a></li>
      <li><a href="tel:+1-505-369-2833">Call</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


@media (max-width: 767px){
ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #045387;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.65rem !important;

}

li {
    display: inline-block;

}

li a {
     display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 60px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 0.65rem;
}

 li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
}
```

Comment: You do realize that your code doesn't produce the minimum output required to implement your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I added to your pen to make it work like you want:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px){
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  ul li {
    flex: 1;
    display: block;
  }
  li a {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

[Updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XVrJmb).

Note you're supposed to use qualified selectors. The ones in this proof-of-concept are way too general to be used in a production level website.
Don't forget to [prefix](https://autoprefixer.github.io).

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the extra information in regards to the prefix. This helps me out a lot!